# Text in modal with pipe translate dont work

Tags: jquery, angular

I have the following modal where it does the delete validation the texts are being traced by a modal always works however after putting in a jquery it only shows the text if I use the keyboard.

my modal

```
<ng-template #msgModal>
        <div class="modal-body" style="padding-top: 10px;">
            <p class="text-center">{{'Deseja deletar o encaminhamento?' | translate}}</p>
            <div style="text-align: center">
                <button (click)="deleteFWResearch(globalId)" class="btn btn-danger">{{'Sim' | translate}}</button>
                <button (click)="modalRef.hide()" class="btn btn-danger">{{'Não' | translate}}</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
```

my function

```
[...]
    @ViewChild('msgModal') msgModal: TemplateRef<any>;
[...]
let self = this;
        $(document).on('click', '.delete', function (data: any) {
            let id = $(this).attr('data-id');
            self.modalRef = self.modalService.show(self.msgModal, {class: 'modal-sm'});
            self.globalId = id;
        });
```

[image: Modal text with pipe translate dont work]

[image: working]

Comment: You have a typo: "$(document).on('click', '.delete'" remove the dot in front of 'delete' and try again. Maybe this helps.

Comment: @DiabolicWords this dot refers a class in icon, when I click on the icon it calls this function